# How to reduce buffering / cause auto-flush when viewing AWS Cloudwatch logs with --follow option

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatch

The *AWS cli* command *logs* is v useful for keeping up with what our instances are doing

I use the following to view our application logs while:

- filtering out the HTTP requests
- filtering out the HealthChecks

```
aws --follow --region=ap-south-1 logs tail "/ECS-CLUSTER/" --since 5h
       | grep -v "GET /" | grep -v "POST /" | grep -v HealthCh
```

This works well - except that the last one to two KB of logs are not displayed. They are apparently not flushed out.  Is there a knob to turn to disable the buffering or to ensure the content is transmitted after some maximum wait say 1000ms?